# is it possible for JSF java application to be a producer of data publishes a message to a Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, jsf, google-cloud-pubsub

is it possible for JSF application (traditional application) to be A producer of data publishes a message to a Pub/Sub topic?

Kindly if there are resources or URL can help me , please advice

Comment: Please expand your question and explain what it is you want to do.

Comment: i have a old java based application include jsf based screens for example add customer screen, and i want with each customer added through this jsf screen  to send this info as message to google pub/sub message broker so that this info will be consumed by other applications 
my question is it possible for jsf based application to integration with google pub/sun? if yes, how is it goint to be ?

Comment: Yes you can easily connect a JSF backing bean to Pub/Sub. There are even java bindings in the central Maven repo. See `google-cloud-pubsub` for more information.

Here are some Java-specific examples; https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library#pubsub-client-libraries-java